# Console command for opening files inside already opened project in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've faced the problem. I use PhpStorm to edit files from FTP server using WinSCP client. In WinSCP client I've set command for using external editor. So, when I try to open php-file from remote FTP server WinSCP downloads this file in temporary file and open it using command provided by me - `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.1.1\bin\phpstorm64.exe" "!.!"`

Earlier, when I used PhpStorm 2019 or 2018, it opened file in already opened window/project. But when I've upgraded to PhpStorm 2020, it started to open file from FTP in separate windows. It's so annoying and some functionality doesn't work in such case (auto suggestions and others).

I know that I can use built-in remote files browser within PhpStorm to view and edit remote files, but I accustomed to use separate FTP client for such purposes.

Does somebody know how to fix this problem? What console command should I use so as to open separate file in already opened window/project?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **LightEdit mode**: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/

**Since 2020.2** you can use the `-p` (`--project`) option instead to force opening files in already opened project windows. For example `idea -p myfile.txt`. [IDEA-237118](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237118)

---

You can also permanently disable that mode by following [these steps](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236868#focus=streamItem-27-4068744.0-0):

- Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (or via `Search Anywhere`: use <kbd>Double Shift</kbd> and switch to `Actions` tab)
- Search for `Registry...` action and select it
- Once in the Registry dialog locate `light.edit.file.open.enabled` entry (just start typing, speed search will narrow it down) and set it to `false` (uncheck the box).
- Not sure if IDE restart is needed (probably not).

Comment: I've added a link your answer to [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_editor#phpstorm). Thanks (upvoted already before).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Cheers! P.S. Just a thought: maybe it is worth clarifying that 1) LightEdit mode is available since 2020.1 version only and 2) from 2020.2 version the `-p` parameter can be used to force opening in already opened project. 3) Maybe use "PhpStorm and other JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm and other)" sort of text as a product name there? Not sure how often users of those IDEs do use WinSCP though...